# Sharing projects in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, projects, sharing

Hello again StackOverflow. I am getting back into developing in XNA/C# with a few buddies of mine across the states. I have setup a server on my computer, installed TFS and Sharepoint, but neither of these seems to have the exact solution that im looking for. I want to be able to share a project with multiple other people, and preferably at the same time be able to edit (dont know if this is possible, ive seen it done with HeroEngine and a few other programs) What is the best way to acheive this? I know I can set up a shared folder with the project in it, but I feel there are many faults to this as version control and overwriting other peoples work. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Git, SVN, etc. Any version control should do the trick

Why don't you use that server of yours and configure it like this http://willperone.net/Code/svnserver.php